# Python ctypes - PyMsiInterop(Windows Installer support) for Python

Tags: python-2.7, callback, windows-installer, ctypes

I am using wxpython to create an installation bootstraper which installs multiple installations
that I have to use MsiSetExternalUI of Windows Installer(msi.dll) to get progress message and then pass some message
to the UI during every installation

I get a windows error as below

```
create argument 1:
ValueError: invalid string pointer 0x0C000000
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "Msi_test.py", line 100, in <module>
      ret = MSI.MsiInstallProductW(msifile, cmdline)
WindowsError: exception: access violation writing 0x0C000068
```

My python code is :

```
import time
from ctypes import *

# Define a python-defined callback function to receive installing msg from MsiSetExternalUI
# It has to parse the received msg and then find out usable msg to pass to python UI in the future 
def MyInstallerHandler(pvContext=None, iMessageType=None, szMessage=None) :
    # print all of data msg
    t = time.time()
    szTime = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(t))
    print szTime + " :: " + str(pvContext)
    print szTime + " :: MyInstallerHandler ::" + str(iMessageType) + ";"+ str(szMessage)


# load msi.dll
print "Load msi.dll"
MSI = WinDLL('msi.dll')

print "Define functions interface of ctypes  "
# define ctypes interface to MsiSetInternalUI of msi.dll
MSI.MsiSetInternalUI.argtypes = (c_uint, POINTER(c_void_p))
MSI.MsiSetInternalUI.restype = c_int

# define ctypes callback interface
callback_type = WINFUNCTYPE(c_int, c_uint, c_wchar_p)
# define ctypes interface to MsiSetExternalUIW of msi.dll
# and assign python callback reference to MsiSetExternalUI's callback function
MSI.MsiSetExternalUIW.argtypes = (callback_type, c_ulong, c_void_p)
MSI.MsiSetExternalUIW.restype = c_int

# define ctypes interface to MsiInstallProductW of msi.dll
MSI.MsiInstallProductW.argtypes = (c_char_p, c_char_p)
MSI.MsiInstallProductW.restype = c_int


# Define Constant 
print "Define Constant : INSTALLUILEVEL "
# INSTALLUILEVEL
INSTALLUILEVEL_NONE = 2
INSTALLUILEVEL_SOURCERESONLY = 256


print "Define Constant : INSTALLMESSAGE "
# INSTALLMESSAGE
INSTALLMESSAGE_FATALEXIT = 0
INSTALLMESSAGE_ERROR = 0x01000000
INSTALLMESSAGE_WARNING = 0x02000000
INSTALLMESSAGE_USER = 0x03000000
INSTALLMESSAGE_INFO = 0x04000000
INSTALLMESSAGE_FILESINUSE = 0x05000000
INSTALLMESSAGE_RESOLVESOURCE = 0x06000000
INSTALLMESSAGE_OUTOFDISKSPACE = 0x07000000
INSTALLMESSAGE_ACTIONSTART = 0x08000000
INSTALLMESSAGE_ACTIONDATA = 0x09000000
INSTALLMESSAGE_PROGRESS = 0x0a000000
INSTALLMESSAGE_COMMONDATA = 0x0b000000
INSTALLMESSAGE_INITIALIZE = 0x0c000000
INSTALLMESSAGE_TERMINATE = 0x0d000000
INSTALLMESSAGE_SHOWDIALOG = 0x0e000000


print "Define Constant : INSTALLLOGMODE "
# INSTALLLOGMODE
INSTALLLOGMODE_FATALEXIT      = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE_FATALEXIT >> 24))
INSTALLLOGMODE_ERROR          = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE_ERROR >> 24))
INSTALLLOGMODE_WARNING        = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE_WARNING >> 24))
INSTALLLOGMODE_USER           = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE_USER >> 24))
INSTALLLOGMODE_INFO           = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE_INFO >> 24))
INSTALLLOGMODE_RESOLVESOURCE  = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE_RESOLVESOURCE >> 24))
INSTALLLOGMODE_OUTOFDISKSPACE = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE_OUTOFDISKSPACE >> 24))
INSTALLLOGMODE_ACTIONSTART    = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE_ACTIONSTART >> 24))
INSTALLLOGMODE_ACTIONDATA     = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE_ACTIONDATA >> 24))
INSTALLLOGMODE_COMMONDATA     = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE_COMMONDATA >> 24))
INSTALLLOGMODE_PROPERTYDUMP   = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE_PROGRESS >> 24))
INSTALLLOGMODE_VERBOSE        = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE_INITIALIZE >> 24))
INSTALLLOGMODE_EXTRADEBUG     = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE_TERMINATE >> 24))
INSTALLLOGMODE_PROGRESS       = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE_PROGRESS >> 24))
INSTALLLOGMODE_INITIALIZE     = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE_INITIALIZE >> 24))
INSTALLLOGMODE_TERMINATE      = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE_TERMINATE >> 24))
INSTALLLOGMODE_SHOWDIALOG     = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE_SHOWDIALOG >> 24))


# Implementf Installation processing
# turn off default MSI UI
MSI.MsiSetInternalUI(INSTALLUILEVEL_NONE|INSTALLUILEVEL_SOURCERESONLY, None);

# Assign a python-defined function to ctypes callback interface
MyPyCallBackFunc = callback_type(MyInstallerHandler) # Create a reference until the procesing is end

INSTALLLOGMODE_ALL = INSTALLLOGMODE_PROGRESS|INSTALLLOGMODE_FATALEXIT|INSTALLLOGMODE_ERROR|INSTALLLOGMODE_WARNING|INSTALLLOGMODE_USER|INSTALLLOGMODE_INFO|INSTALLLOGMODE_RESOLVESOURCE|INSTALLLOGMODE_OUTOFDISKSPACE|INSTALLLOGMODE_ACTIONSTART|INSTALLLOGMODE_ACTIONDATA|INSTALLLOGMODE_COMMONDATA|INSTALLLOGMODE_PROGRESS|INSTALLLOGMODE_INITIALIZE|INSTALLLOGMODE_TERMINATE|INSTALLLOGMODE_SHOWDIALOG

szMsg = "msi SetExternalUI test"

MSI.MsiSetExternalUIW(MyPyCallBackFunc, INSTALLLOGMODE_ALL, szMsg) 

# Launch msi installing
print "Launch InstallProduct"
msifile = 'D:\\MdxSetup_Layout\\MsiSetExternUI\\MsiSetExternUI.msi'
cmdline = None
ret = MSI.MsiInstallProductW(msifile, cmdline)   

# Close msi.dll
print "Release msi.dll"
del MSI
```

I use python 2.7

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks in advance

M.Chou

---------- 2014/07/02 Update --------

It is worked temporarily when using English path of msi file only.
I modified two parts and do more logging in my code

part 1 : 
Callback prototype is wrong as @eryksun said
It should be callback_type = WINFUNCTYPE(c_int, c_int, c_uint, c_wchar_p)

part 2 : 
I use MsiInstallProductA(ANSI) instead of MsiInstallProductW(Unicode).

There is a problem that MsiInstallProductA is for English path of msi file only.

It is failed to run installing that I get an error shows msi file not found and I found the msi file path is unreadable characters in msi log 
if i use MsiInstallProductW and even though the msi path is pure English path

I have no idea about how to solve it now.

M.Chou

----------------- Code -----------------------

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#-----------------------------------------------------------------
# PyMsiInterop
# Purpose : Get installing detail data while insatlling a msi file
# WIndows Installer support. 
# Auther : Morris C.J Chou (2014/06/26) 
# Version : 
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
import time, os
from ctypes import *
import logging
import re
import msilib

# msi message output logfile
logfile = 'D:\\PyMsiInterop-3.log'
logging.basicConfig(filename=logfile, level=logging.DEBUG)    


# Define a python-defined callback function to receive installing msg from MsiSetExternalUI
# It has to parse the received msg and then find out usable msg to pass to python UI in the future 
def MyInstallerHandler(pvContext=None, iMessageType=None, szMessage=None) :
    # print all of data msg
    nResult = 0
    intProgressStep = None

    t = time.time()
    szTime = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(t))
    print szTime + " :: " + str(pvContext)
    logging.debug(szTime + " :: pvContext = " + str(pvContext))

    if iMessageType == INSTALLMESSAGE_ACTIONDATA :
        print szTime + " :: INSTALLMESSAGE_ACTIONDATA ::" + str(iMessageType) + ";"+ str(szMessage)
        logging.debug(szTime + " :: INSTALLMESSAGE_ACTIONDATA ::" + str(iMessageType) + ";"+ str(szMessage))


    elif iMessageType == INSTALLMESSAGE_PROGRESS :
        print szTime + " :: INSTALLMESSAGE_PROGRESS ::" + str(iMessageType) + ";"+ str(szMessage)
        logging.debug(szTime + " :: INSTALLMESSAGE_PROGRESS ::" + str(iMessageType) + ";"+ str(szMessage))

        ret = ParseProgressStep(iMessageType, szMessage)
        if ret[0] == True :
            intProgressStep = ret[1]


    elif iMessageType == INSTALLMESSAGE_ACTIONSTART :
        print szTime + " :: INSTALLMESSAGE_ACTIONSTART ::" + str(iMessageType) + ";"+ str(szMessage)
        logging.debug(szTime + " :: INSTALLMESSAGE_ACTIONSTART ::" + str(iMessageType) + ";"+ str(szMessage))


    elif iMessageType == INSTALLMESSAGE_COMMONDATA :
        print szTime + " :: INSTALLMESSAGE_COMMONDATA ::" + str(iMessageType) + ";"+ str(szMessage)
        logging.debug(szTime + " :: INSTALLMESSAGE_COMMONDATA ::" + str(iMessageType) + ";"+ str(szMessage))


    elif iMessageType == INSTALLMESSAGE_ERROR :
        print szTime + " :: INSTALLMESSAGE_ERROR ::" + str(iMessageType) + ";"+ str(szMessage)
        logging.debug(szTime + " :: INSTALLMESSAGE_ERROR ::" + str(iMessageType) + ";"+ str(szMessage))


    elif iMessageType == INSTALLMESSAGE_FATALEXIT :
        print szTime + " :: INSTALLMESSAGE_FATALEXIT ::" + str(iMessageType) + ";"+ str(szMessage)
        logging.debug(szTime + " :: INSTALLMESSAGE_FATALEXIT ::" + str(iMessageType) + ";"+ str(szMessage))


    elif iMessageType == INSTALLMESSAGE_FILESINUSE :
        print szTime + " :: INSTALLMESSAGE_FILESINUSE ::" + str(iMessageType) + ";"+ str(szMessage)
        logging.debug(szTime + " :: INSTALLMESSAGE_FILESINUSE ::" + str(iMessageType) + ";"+ str(szMessage))


    elif iMessageType == INSTALLMESSAGE_INFO :
        print szTime + " :: INSTALLMESSAGE_INFO ::" + str(iMessageType) + ";"+ str(szMessage)
        logging.debug(szTime + " :: INSTALLMESSAGE_INFO ::" + str(iMessageType) + ";"+ str(szMessage))


    elif iMessageType == INSTALLMESSAGE_INITIALIZE :
        print szTime + " :: INSTALLMESSAGE_INITIALIZE ::" + str(iMessageType) + ";"+ str(szMessage)
        logging.debug(szTime + " :: INSTALLMESSAGE_INITIALIZE ::" + str(iMessageType) + ";"+ str(szMessage))


    elif iMessageType == INSTALLMESSAGE_OUTOFDISKSPACE :
        print szTime + " :: INSTALLMESSAGE_OUTOFDISKSPACE ::" + str(iMessageType) + ";"+ str(szMessage)
        logging.debug(szTime + " :: INSTALLMESSAGE_OUTOFDISKSPACE ::" + str(iMessageType) + ";"+ str(szMessage))


    elif iMessageType == INSTALLMESSAGE_RESOLVESOURCE :
        print szTime + " :: INSTALLMESSAGE_RESOLVESOURCE ::" + str(iMessageType) + ";"+ str(szMessage)
        logging.debug(szTime + " :: INSTALLMESSAGE_RESOLVESOURCE ::" + str(iMessageType) + ";"+ str(szMessage))


    elif iMessageType == INSTALLLOGMODE_SHOWDIALOG :
        print szTime + " :: INSTALLLOGMODE_SHOWDIALOG ::" + str(iMessageType) + ";"+ str(szMessage)
        logging.debug(szTime + " :: INSTALLLOGMODE_SHOWDIALOG ::" + str(iMessageType) + ";"+ str(szMessage))


    elif iMessageType == INSTALLMESSAGE_TERMINATE :
        print szTime + " :: INSTALLMESSAGE_TERMINATE ::" + str(iMessageType) + ";"+ str(szMessage)
        logging.debug(szTime + " :: INSTALLMESSAGE_TERMINATE ::" + str(iMessageType) + ";"+ str(szMessage))


    elif iMessageType == INSTALLLOGMODE_USER :
        print szTime + " :: INSTALLLOGMODE_USER ::" + str(iMessageType) + ";"+ str(szMessage)
        logging.debug(szTime + " :: INSTALLLOGMODE_USER ::" + str(iMessageType) + ";"+ str(szMessage))


    elif iMessageType == INSTALLMESSAGE_WARNING :
        print szTime + " :: INSTALLMESSAGE_WARNING ::" + str(iMessageType) + ";"+ str(szMessage)
        logging.debug(szTime + " :: INSTALLMESSAGE_WARNING ::" + str(iMessageType) + ";"+ str(szMessage))


    # Send installing detali progress value and msg to UI  
    #if (szInstallMsg <> None) or (intProgressStep <> None)  :    
        #SendProgressMsgToUI(UI_Signal, intProgressStep, szInstallMsg)
        #pass

    return nResult

def LogInstallMsg() :
    pass

def ParseInstallMsg(iMessageType, szMessage) :
    # Filter out useful msg to pass to UI
    # e.g. INSTALLMESSAGE_ACTIONDATA ::150994944;File: teapot.ppm,  Directory: C:\Program Files\Molding\My Product Name\tcl\tk8.5\demos\images\,  Size: 196623
    # iMessageType = 150994944
    # szMessage = File: teapot.ppm,  Directory: C:\Program Files\Molding\My Product Name\tcl\tk8.5\demos\images\,  Size: 196623

    nResult = 0
    return nResult, szInstallMsg

def ParseProgressStep(iMessageType, szMessage) :
    # e.g. INSTALLMESSAGE_PROGRESS ::167772160;1: 2 2: 32768 3: 0 4: 0
    # iMessageType = 167772160
    # szMessage = 1: 2 2: 32768 3: 0 4: 0
    nResult = False
    intProgressStep = None
    if szMessage <> "" :
        pattern = '2:\s\d+'
        match = re.search(pattern,szMessage)  
        szString = match.group()  # szString = '2: 32768'
        pattern = '\s\d+'
        match = re.search(pattern,szString)  
        szStep = match.group().strip()   # szString = '32768'
        intProgressStep = int(szStep)
        nResult = True
        logging.debug("INSTALLMESSAGE_PROGRESS :: Get intProgressStep = " + str(intProgressStep))

    return nResult, intProgressStep


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# GetRequiredSizeFromMSI(self, MSI_path):
# Input : msi file path
# Return : Required Size
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def GetRequiredSizeFromMSI(self, MSI_path):
    total_size = 0
    if os.path.exists(MSI_path) == True :
    db = msilib.OpenDatabase(MSI_path, msilib.MSIDBOPEN_READONLY) 
    #view = db.OpenView("SELECT FileName, FileSize FROM File where Component_ in ('Component_1', 'Component_2')") 
    view = db.OpenView("SELECT FileName, FileSize FROM File") 
    view.Execute(None)
    i =0 
    while True:
        try :
        record = view.Fetch()
        i += 1
        if not record: 
            break
        else :
            print str(i) + " : " + record.GetString(1), record.GetString(2)
            logging.debug("GetRequiredSizeFromMSI :: File:" + record.GetString(1) + " Size:" + record.GetString(2))
            total_size += int(record.GetString(2))
        except :
        break
    print total_size
    logging.debug("GetRequiredSizeFromMSI :: Required Space Size : " + str(total_size))

    return  total_size 



def SendProgressMsgToUI(UI_Signal, ProgressPercent, ProgressMsg) :
    pass






# load msi.dll
print "Load msi.dll"
MSI = WinDLL('msi.dll')


print "Define functions interface of ctypes  "
# define ctypes interface to MsiSetInternalUI of msi.dll
MSI.MsiSetInternalUI.argtypes = (c_uint, POINTER(c_void_p))
MSI.MsiSetInternalUI.restype = c_int


# define ctypes callback interface
callback_type = WINFUNCTYPE(c_int, c_int, c_uint, c_wchar_p)
# define ctypes interface to MsiSetExternalUIW of msi.dll
# and assign python callback reference to MsiSetExternalUI's callback function
MSI.MsiSetExternalUIW.argtypes = (callback_type, c_ulong, c_void_p)
MSI.MsiSetExternalUIW.restype = c_int


# define ctypes interface to MsiInstallProductW of msi.dll
MSI.MsiInstallProductA.argtypes = (c_char_p, c_char_p)
MSI.MsiInstallProductA.restype = c_int


# Define Constant 
print "Define Constant : INSTALLUILEVEL "
# INSTALLUILEVEL
INSTALLUILEVEL_NONE = 2
INSTALLUILEVEL_SOURCERESONLY = 256


print "Define Constant : INSTALLMESSAGE "
# INSTALLMESSAGE
INSTALLMESSAGE_FATALEXIT = 0
INSTALLMESSAGE_ERROR = 0x01000000
INSTALLMESSAGE_WARNING = 0x02000000
INSTALLMESSAGE_USER = 0x03000000
INSTALLMESSAGE_INFO = 0x04000000
INSTALLMESSAGE_FILESINUSE = 0x05000000
INSTALLMESSAGE_RESOLVESOURCE = 0x06000000
INSTALLMESSAGE_OUTOFDISKSPACE = 0x07000000
INSTALLMESSAGE_ACTIONSTART = 0x08000000
INSTALLMESSAGE_ACTIONDATA = 0x09000000
INSTALLMESSAGE_PROGRESS = 0x0a000000
INSTALLMESSAGE_COMMONDATA = 0x0b000000
INSTALLMESSAGE_INITIALIZE = 0x0c000000
INSTALLMESSAGE_TERMINATE = 0x0d000000
INSTALLMESSAGE_SHOWDIALOG = 0x0e000000


print "Define Constant : INSTALLLOGMODE "
# INSTALLLOGMODE
INSTALLLOGMODE_FATALEXIT      = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE_FATALEXIT >> 24))
INSTALLLOGMODE_ERROR          = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE_ERROR >> 24))
INSTALLLOGMODE_WARNING        = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE_WARNING >> 24))
INSTALLLOGMODE_USER           = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE_USER >> 24))
INSTALLLOGMODE_INFO           = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE_INFO >> 24))
INSTALLLOGMODE_RESOLVESOURCE  = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE_RESOLVESOURCE >> 24))
INSTALLLOGMODE_OUTOFDISKSPACE = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE_OUTOFDISKSPACE >> 24))
INSTALLLOGMODE_ACTIONSTART    = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE_ACTIONSTART >> 24))
INSTALLLOGMODE_ACTIONDATA     = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE_ACTIONDATA >> 24))
INSTALLLOGMODE_COMMONDATA     = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE_COMMONDATA >> 24))
INSTALLLOGMODE_PROPERTYDUMP   = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE_PROGRESS >> 24))
INSTALLLOGMODE_VERBOSE        = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE_INITIALIZE >> 24))
INSTALLLOGMODE_EXTRADEBUG     = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE_TERMINATE >> 24))
INSTALLLOGMODE_PROGRESS       = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE_PROGRESS >> 24))
INSTALLLOGMODE_INITIALIZE     = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE_INITIALIZE >> 24))
INSTALLLOGMODE_TERMINATE      = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE_TERMINATE >> 24))
INSTALLLOGMODE_SHOWDIALOG     = (1 << (INSTALLMESSAGE_SHOWDIALOG >> 24))

INSTALLLOGMODE_ALL = INSTALLLOGMODE_PROGRESS|INSTALLLOGMODE_FATALEXIT|INSTALLLOGMODE_ERROR|INSTALLLOGMODE_WARNING|INSTALLLOGMODE_USER|INSTALLLOGMODE_INFO|INSTALLLOGMODE_RESOLVESOURCE|INSTALLLOGMODE_OUTOFDISKSPACE|INSTALLLOGMODE_ACTIONSTART|INSTALLLOGMODE_ACTIONDATA|INSTALLLOGMODE_COMMONDATA|INSTALLLOGMODE_INITIALIZE|INSTALLLOGMODE_TERMINATE|INSTALLLOGMODE_SHOWDIALOG


# Implementf Installation processing
# turn off default MSI UI
MSI.MsiSetInternalUI(INSTALLUILEVEL_NONE|INSTALLUILEVEL_SOURCERESONLY, None);

# Assign a python-defined function to ctypes callback interface
MyPyCallBackFunc = callback_type(MyInstallerHandler) # Create a reference until the procesing is end

szMsg = "msi SetExternalUI test"

MSI.MsiSetExternalUIW(MyPyCallBackFunc, INSTALLLOGMODE_ALL, szMsg) 

# Launch msi installing
print "Launch InstallProduct"
msifile = 'D:\\MdxSetup_Layout\\MsiSetExternUI\\MsiSetExternUI.msi'
cmdline = ''
#print msifile
#print msifile.decode('utf-8')
#ret = MSI.MsiInstallProductW(msifile.decode('utf-8'), cmdline)
ret = MSI.MsiInstallProductA(msifile, cmdline)

print ret

# Close msi.dll
print "Release msi.dll"
del MSI
```

Comment: Your callback prototype is incorrect. The first parameter of [`WINFUNCTYPE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE) is the result type, e.g. `c_int`.

Comment: @eryksun Thank you, I am not a C++ programmer, the type conversion is a big  problem for me